# Error with resque-web: Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

Tags: file-descriptor, resque

I'm trying start resque-web, but this error occurs:

```
[Sun Mar 06 05:27:48 +0000 2011] Starting 'resque-web'...
[Sun Mar 06 05:27:48 +0000 2011] trying port 8281...
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

This error occurred with Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10.

Resque Web only starts with **-F** option (don't daemonize, run in the foreground). So, it must be something when the process is daemonized.

Any idea, how can I solve it?

Regards,

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's probably trying to open the default browser and failing to do so. Try using:

```
$ resque-web -L
```

To avoid starting a browser.

Comment: Thanks deluan. With *-L* option resque-web started too.